# How to get data from the form

Tags: php, sql, database

```
<form name="screenDishForm"  action="bentoQuery.php"  method="POST"> 
        <!--Label and input for the name of dish -->
            <label class="contentLabel"> Name: </label><br> 
            <input class="inputField" type="text" id="dishName" name="dishName" placeholder="E.g. Beef Teriyaki" required><br>
                        
    <!-- Label and Drop down list for the type of dish -->
            <label class="contentLabel"> Type: </label><br> 
            <select class = "inputField" id="dishType" name = "dishType">
                   <option value="mainDish">Main Dish</option>
                   <option value="sideDish">Side Dish</option>
                   <option value="soup">Soup</option>
            </select><br>
                     
    <!--Label and input for the price of dishes -->
            <label class="contentLabel"> Price: </label> <br>
            <input class="inputField" type="number" minimum="0" id="dishPrice" name="dishPrice" required><br>
                    
    <!--Button that will be used to register the dishes. -->
           <button class="btnRegister" type="submit" name="submit"> Register Dish </button>

 </form>
```

This is my form which I named as bentoApp.php

```
   <?php
     require_once 'dbConn.php';

         $dishName = $_POST['dishName'];
         $dishType = $_POST['dishType'];
         $dishPrice = $_POST['dishPrice'];

       $sql = "INSERT INTO dish(dishName, dishType, dishPrice)
        VALUES ('$this->dishName', '$this->dishType', '$this->dishPrice')";

  ?>
```

This is my BentoQuery.php's content

How am I going to get the data of the form ?
It turns out an error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: so, where's the class for all this? If you're not using a class, then why are you using `$this->` instead of variables? You also never executed the query neither and we have no way of knowing which API you're using to connect with.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your variables $dishName, $dishType, $dishPrice.

`$this` is used to refer to the current instance of the object you're using it within. You're not currently using any objects.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$this->` from your mysql Values variables. I am assuming that you made an error here, if not the problem is that you assigned the posted values to variables but are not using those. You wrote them as if you were referring to an instance of an object which you currently do not have and even that would be incorrect.

This is what your code should look like.

```
   <?php
     require_once 'dbConn.php';

         $dishName = $_POST['dishName'];
         $dishType = $_POST['dishType'];
         $dishPrice = $_POST['dishPrice'];

       $sql = "INSERT INTO dish(dishName, dishType, dishPrice)
        VALUES ('$dishName', '$dishType', $dishPrice)";

  ?>
```

Comment: `VALUES ($dishName, $dishType, $dishPrice)` will still thrown an error, just a different one. Plus, that query never got executed neither.

Comment: I am not the person who posted the question.

Comment: Also the questions was not that he did not know how to execute a query. I answered his question using the code he provided.